# Access parent scope from nested class

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have a main class e.g.

```
class MY_API {
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->something = new MY_SOMETHING($db);
        $this->anotherthing = new MY_ANOTHERTHING($db);
    }
}
```

SO I can access this with 
    `$this->something->somefunction();`

But I am not sure how I could access:

```
$this->anotherthing->anotherfunction();
```

From within:

```
$this->something->somefunction();
```

I imagine I would need something like:

```
$this->parent->anotherthing->anotherfunction();
```

Is this possible at all, or do I need to change the way I am building the classes?

Ideally I just want these functions to sit in a different file rather than having one very large file and have each function in each file accessible to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MY_SOMETHING` has a dependency on `MY_ANOTHERTHING`, inject it!

```
class MY_SOMETHING {
  private $db;
  private $anotherThing;

  public function __construct($db, MY_ANOTHERTHING $anotherThing) {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->anotherThing = $anotherThing;
  }
```

and in your `MY_API` constructor

```
public function __construct($db) {
    $this->anotherthing = new MY_ANOTHERTHING($db);
    $this->something = new MY_SOMETHING($db, $this->anotherThing);
}
```

Now your `MY_SOMETHING` class can use `$this->anotherThing` in any of its methods.

Comment: OK this makes sense, what about if they each need to access functions from each other? 

ideally I would like to have all classes to have access to all the other classes so I can organise my code easily

Comment: That sounds less like organisation and more like a huge mess. Perhaps you don't want to use OOP and instead, just want a bunch of functions (global or namespaced)

Comment: thanks Phil, it works when all the functions sit within the main class, however I am simply trying to break the code up between different files, hence splitting some functions out into their own classes, this however stops me from being able to reference each subclass functions, 

extending the class doesn't seem to be a good solution, maybe I will just need to deal with one very long class file

Comment: I recommend you read about the [SOLID principals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) regarding OOP with particular focus on the **S** ~ _"Single responsibility principle - 
a class should have only a single responsibility"_